# Valores quebradas em parcelas, como inserir na primeira a 3ª casa decimal?

Tags: php

Tenho uma solução que divide as parcelas e inclui o valor do resto da divisão na primeira parcela, como é possível verificar o mesmo funcionando em [phpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/y98t-hfm2)

mas tenho problemas quando os valores possuem ponto flutuante como por exemplo 190.75 já estou usando a função `number_format` para fazer conversão monetária.

da forma que está funciona se o valor total for inteiro, mas não queria que fosse como eu fiz, na verdade queria que fosse assim.

```
$valor_total = 200.75;
$qt_parcelas = 3;
$valor_parcelas = $valor_total / $qt_parcelas;

echo 'o valor de cada parcela eh: '.$valor_parcelas; //cada parcela seria 66.916666..
// mas queria que ficasse assim
// parcela 1: 66.93
// parcela 2: 66.91
// parcela 3: 66.91
```

Existe alguma maneira de fazer isto em php? pegar os valores depois da 2 casa decimal e somar com o valor da primeira?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em último caso, você sempre pode trabalhar com centavos:

```
<?php
$valor_total = 200.75;
$qtde_parcelas = 3;
function parcelas($montante, $parcelas) {
    $resultado = array();
    $centavos = $montante * 100; // montante em centavos

    // a primeira parcela recebe o resto;
    // divide tudo por 100 para achar o valor em reais
    array_push($resultado,(floor($centavos / $parcelas) + $centavos % $parcelas) / 100.0 );
    for ($i = 1; $i < $parcelas; $i ++) {
        // as outras são arredondadas para baixo somente
        array_push($resultado, floor($centavos / $parcelas)  / 100.0 );
    }

    return $resultado;
}
print_r(parcelas($valor_total, $qtde_parcelas));
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar `round()` por exemplo, `round($valor_parcelas);`

Ou

`round($valor_parcelas, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_ODD);`

Comment: round não me ajuda pois não posso arredondar para cima ou para baixo, pois preciso retornar o valor real no final da minha aplicação e não posso apresentar valores com diferenças de centavos. obrigado.